# php loop is skipping or missing some results of mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sqlyog

php loop is skipping or missing some results of mysql query, the same query is bringing 181 results in PhpMyAdmin and even in sqlYOG where as the loop is bringing only 175

```
$queryos = "SELECT * FROM OSCSBranch AS a 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ItemCode AS icode FROM NonFood
) AS q ON a.ItemCode = q.icode
WHERE a.BranchId = '$bid' AND a.BType = 'O' AND DATE(a.BDate) = '$date'"; 

$osquery = mysqli_query($conn, $queryos);
if(!$osquery)
{
die("QUERY FAILED OS " . mysqli_error($conn));    
} 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($osquery)){
$total[$row['ItemCode']] = $row['TotalQuantity'];
}
```

Comment: MAY BE SOME RECORD ARE DUPLICATED AND DUE TO  `$total[$row['ItemCode']]` THE NEW RECORD OF SAME ID IS REPLACINGTO THE OLDER ONE

Comment: @anant the `($row->num_rows;)` i also tried the count variable it is also bringing me 175 results, this is weird as it only happened this time is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like some records have same `'ItemCode'`.

So due to `$row['ItemCode'] = ....`

the new data of same `ItemCode` is replacing the older value again and again and due to that you are getting 175 record instead of 181

So you can do it like below:-

Either:-

```
$total[] = $row['TotalQuantity']; will give you like array(0=>array('name'=>'a',....)....)
```

Or

```
$total[$row['ItemCode']][] = $row['TotalQuantity']; //will  give you like array('item201'=>array(0=>array(),1=>array(),...),....) (an example)
```

Comment: the `$total` array is i guess not the issue as the results that are fetched were check by
`$count = 0;`
`while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($osquery)){`
`$total[$row['ItemCode']] = $row['TotalQuantity'];`
`$count++;`
`}  `
`echo $count;` 
this is also bringing 175, and num_rows is also brining 175

Comment: @YasarKhalid  are you sure that same query with hardcoded value gave 181 record ? while same query with same values via php giving 175 record?

Comment: yes i am sure about it @anant only 5 items are missing and i am unable to figure it out why

Comment: @YasarKhalid  do one thing :- before `$osquery = mysqli_query($conn, $queryos);` write `echo $queryos;die;` and then copy that query and run it to PhpMyAdmin or sqlYOG  and check how many records are coming

Comment: @YasarKhalid  glad to help you .:):)